# Link to a new page into a plugin

Tags: customization

I am developing a new plugins, I added a new admin page menu with:

```
function ca_admin_link()
{
add_menu_page(
     'Checklist Artistas', 
     'Checklist Artistas', 
'checklist-artistas/includes/ca-checklist-acp-page.php' 
     );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ca_admin_link' );
```

Everything ok, an item menu is shown and I can access to ca-checklist-acp-page.php but en this page I want to link to another page (ca-edit-checklist-acp-page.php) into same directory.

Using

```
admin_url('admin.php?page=checklist-artistas/includes/ca_edit_checklist_acp-page.php')
```

but when I try to access to that new page I get "You do not have permission to access to this page"

How to give admin permissions to ca_edit_checklist_acp-page.php?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This work :)

```
function ca_admin_link()
{
     // My code goes here
     add_menu_page(
     'Checklist Artistas', // Title of the page
     'Checklist Artistas', // Text to show on the menu link
     'manage_options', // Capability requirement to see the link
     'checklist-artistas/includes/ca-checklist-acp-page.php' // The 'slug' - file to display when clicking the link
     );

    // This is the first page that is displayed when the menu is clicked
    add_submenu_page(
      null, 
      'Checklist Artistas',
      'Checklist Artistas', 
      'manage_options', 
      'ca_edit_checklist_acp_page.php', 
      'ca_details_page_callback'
     );

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ca_admin_link' );

function ca_details_page_callback() {
    echo "Hola";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the 'slug' argument incorrectly. This is not for which file to load for the menu page. `add_menu_page()` does not load a file, it loads a *callback function* (the 5th argument). Any code you want to display needs to go in that callback function.

So the slug should not be a filename, it should just be a unique ID, like `checklist-artistas`, without `.php`. Note this from [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) (emphasis mine):

> The slug name to refer to this menu by. Should be unique for this menu
>   page and **only include lowercase alphanumeric, dashes, and underscores**
>   characters to be compatible with sanitize_key().

`.` and `/`, which you've included as part of the filename, are not allowed in the slug.

You've also used the argument in the wrong place. The 3rd argument is the *capability* the user needs to see the menu page. The slug should be the 4th argument.

You code should look more like this:

```
function ca_admin_link()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Checklist Artistas', 
        'Checklist Artistas',
        'manage_options', // Capability required to view
        'checklist-artistas', // Slug
        'ca_menu_page' // Callback function
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ca_admin_link' );

function ca_menu_page() {
    // Output page code here.
}
```

Then you can link to the page with

```
admin_url( 'admin.php?page=checklist-artistas' );
```